# user logged even if password or email are wrong laravel react

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I'm not using the default authentication. I'm facing a problem where the user is logged in even if the email or the password is not correct.

**UserController.php**

```
//login
function login(Request $req) {        
    $user = User::where('email', $req->email)->first();
    if(!$user || !Hash::check($req->password, $user->password)) {
        return ["error"=> "Email or password is not matched"];
    }
    return $user;
}
```

**Login.js**

```
async function login() {
    let item = {
        email, 
        password
    }
    let result = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers:{
            "content-type":"application/json",
            "Accept":"*/*"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(item)
    });
    result = await result.json();
    console.warn(result)
    localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(result))
    history.push('/homepage')
}
```

Comment: In your code, you set the local storage item with your result if there is an error. What does your result contain?

Comment: `{error: "Email or password is not matched"`

Comment: are you using Sanctum or Passport?

Comment: I didn't use any